# how to get seperate multiple dict pairs from a list to new line in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dictionary output in below format in JSON File:

```
[{"Status": "NEW", "ID": "1", "type": "type1"},{"Status": "NEW", "ID": "2", "type": "type1"}]
```

I would like to have this in seperate line in JSON file:

```
{"Status": "NEW", "ID": "1", "type": "type1"}
{"Status": "NEW", "ID": "2", "type": "type1"}
```

Code I have is:

```
# I have to convert dataframe to dictionary first and then remove all null objects
json_dict=df.to_dict('records')
def remove_empty_elements(d):
    """recursively remove empty lists, empty dicts, or None elements from a dictionary"""

    def empty(x):
        return x is None or x == {} or x == []

    if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
        return d
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [v for v in (remove_empty_elements(v) for v in d) if not empty(v)]
    else:
        return {k: v for k, v in ((k, remove_empty_elements(v)) for k, v in d.items()) if not empty(v)}

data=remove_empty_elements(json_dict)
with open("nonnullfile.json", 'w') as fout:
    json_dumps_str = json.dumps(data)
    print(json_dumps_str, file=fout)
```

This code gives me output with a list of dictionaries but I would like to see in separate lines.
I can do this using `iterrows()` and write in new line but that is very very slow.

Can anyone help me if there is any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `indent` argument in `json.dumps`.

```py
# ... your preceding code ... #

with open("nonnullfile.json", 'w') as fout:
    json_dumps_str = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

# ... everything else ... #
```

Comment: indent is not working. I tried with indent 2,3,4,6 .

Comment: Using your example data, this worked fine for me, even when I run it through your remove_empty_elements function. Can you provide a reproducible example with your dataframe before conversion to a list of dicts using to_dict?

Answer (score 1):

When you call remove_empty_elements and the return value `data` is a list, you can do:

```
with open("nonnullfile.json", 'w') as fout:
    for element in data:
        element_json_dumps_str = json.dumps(element)
        print(element_json_dumps_str, file=fout)
```

This way you'll be able to write each dictionary of your list in a new line of your json file.